# Select all lines after last occurrence of a certain character

Tags: regex

```
TITLE
——
1 nuit 
1 nuit 
1 nuit 
1 nuit 
1 nuit 
total : 5 nuits 
——
1 nuit 
1 nuit
1 nuit
total : 3 nuits 
——
1 nuit 
1 nuit
1 nuit
1 nuit
1 nuit
1 nuit
```

and so on ...

I'm having this paragraph in which I'd like to select the last lines after the occurrence of the last `——`.
It should match and group the 6 following lines right after the `——`... I've tried pretty much everything that crossed my mind so far but I must be missing something here.
I tested `(?s:.*\s)\K——` that is able to match the last `——` of the document. But I can't seem to be able to select the lines after that match.

The point here is to count the lines after that. So if I'm only able to select the "1" or "nuit" that's fine.

The expected capture:

```
1 nuit 
1 nuit
1 nuit
1 nuit
1 nuit
1 nuit
```

Comment: So what about `(?!.*^——)^.*` for example? Assuming notepad++ you can make a dot match newlines too.

Comment: It would be helpful if the input had different numbers on each line so we can relate them to the output.

Comment: @JvdV it matches the title to me... i'm testing here https://regex101.com/

Comment: @AdrianHHH Yeah, but that's not really how the file works... I wouldn't need help if it did haha.

Comment: @Aurore, works for me. Another option when you just want to return the count of 6 is to `Find` pattern `(?!.*^——)^\d` and click `Count`. Again assuming notepad++ and have a dot matching newline.

Comment: Is [`(?<=——\n)(?:(?!——).)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/U2FyQx/1) what you're looking for ? (note the flags, single-line must be enabled and multi-line disabled)

Comment: @Aaron It's weird, it doesn't match anything to me on https://regexr.com/ ...

Comment: Have you set the correct flags ? https://regexr.com/7u8mj seems to work. If it doesn't work for you, try switching from the javascript execution to the server-side PCRE execution, your browser might not support lookbehinds

Comment: You need to mention the regex environemnt where you're doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the pattern like this if there is no single dangling `——` at the bottom, but that would give you a single match of all the lines:

```
(?s).*^——$\R\K.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7g3gji/1)

If you want separate matches (to count them), you could write the pattern as:

```
(?:[\s\S]*^——$|\G(?!^))\R\K.+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[\s\S]*` Match all the way to the end of the file
  - `^——$` Match `——` on a single line
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\R\K` Match a newline and then forget what is matched so far
- `.+` Match a whole line with one or more characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/At2M7O/1)

Or if there can not be a single `——` at the bottom:

```
(?:[\s\S]*^——$|\G(?!^))\R\K(?!^——$).+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eDQzuB/1)

For example in a tool like Notepad++:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very complete and working. :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution using awk:

```
awk  "!/ /{ n=0 }/ /{ n++ }END{if(n!=0){ print \"total :\", n, \"nuits\";}}"  nuits.txt
```

When input is named `nuits.txt`, this will produce:

```
total : 6 nuits
```

NOTE: I am testing for a space in the lines, because the UTF-8 character is hard to match on a command-line in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

this would be a solution in Python. It reads the file from input.txt and counts the occurrances between the character "——". Then it writes the number of lines found per block to output.txt. I hope this meets your needs.

```
'''
parses the file input.txt in the same path
as this python file
and counts the occurrences of a keyword2 (kw2) 
in blocks around kw1
'''
import pathlib
import re
kw1 = "——"
kw2 = "^[\d]+ nuit"

def write_to_output(res_kw):
    fout = open("output.txt", 'a')
    for cnt in res_kw:
        fout.write(str(cnt) + "\n")
    fout.close()

path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
print(path)
finput = open("input.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
lines = finput.readlines()
block = []
for i in range(len(lines)):
    if re.search(kw1, lines[i]):
        block.append(i)

nuit = [0]*(len(block)-1)

i = 1
while i < len(block):
    start = block[i - 1]
    end = block[i]
    for line in lines[start : end]:
        if re.search(kw2, line):
            nuit[i-1] += 1
        else:
            pass
    start = end
    i += 1


write_to_output(nuit)
```

The output of the code would be the number of lines with "x nuit" without "total ...":
5
3
6